# How to effective verify a method if it called during unit test with Powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

When I used Powermock to mock a private method, and then verify it in another method's unit test, to check if it was called and with correct times. But I found I can verify whether the method was called and with the correct param, the called times of the method can be any number, however the unit test always passed. If someone can help me solve the problem. thx!

This is my source code:

```
public enum ConversionCommon{
INSTANCE;

...

public void getConvertTypeData(JSONObject result, JSONObject conversionData, String intent){
    String uncertainty = "";
    String unit1 = "";
    String unit1_char = "";
    if(result.has(ConversionDefine.CONVERSION_UNCERTAINTY)){
        uncertainty = result.getString(ConversionDefine.CONVERSION_UNCERTAINTY);
    }
    if(result.has(ConversionDefine.CONVERSION_UNIT1)){
        unit1 = result.getString(ConversionDefine.CONVERSION_UNIT1);
    }
    if(result.has(ConversionDefine.CONVERSION_UNIT1_CHAR)){
        unit1_char = result.getString(ConversionDefine.CONVERSION_UNIT1_CHAR);
    }

    setUnitCount(conversionData, uncertainty, intent);
    setDestUnits(conversionData, unit1, unit1_char);

}
```

}

The method getConvertTypeData() calls two methods once. The follow is my test case code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ConversionCommon.class, LengthConversion.class })
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")

public class ConversionCommonTest{

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception{
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(LengthConversion.class);//
    PowerMockito.spy(LengthConversion.class); //
}

@Test
public void should_getConvertTypeData_invoke_setUnitCount() throws Exception{
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject conversionData = new JSONObject();
    result.put(ConversionDefine.CONVERSION_UNCERTAINTY, "3");
    result.put(ConversionDefine.CONVERSION_UNIT1, "meter");
    result.put(ConversionDefine.CONVERSION_UNIT1_CHAR, "centmeter");

    suppress(method(ConversionCommon.class, "setUnitCount", JSONObject.class, String.class, String.class));
    ConversionCommon.INSTANCE.getConvertTypeData(result, conversionData, ConversionDefine.INTENT_LENGTH_CONVERSION);
    PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(ConversionCommon.INSTANCE, Mockito.times(1)).invoke("setUnitCount", Mockito.anyObject(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
}
```

The test case can run successful but if I change the last line to ...

```
PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(ConversionCommon.INSTANCE, Mockito.times(100)).invoke("setUnitCount", Mockito.anyObject(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
```

... and re-run the test case. The result is also passed. But in fact I only call the method `setUnitCount` only once in `Refo`.

The edition of test framework: mockito:1.10.19;powermock:1.6.5

How can I correct verify the private method's call times with the API PowerMockito.verifyPrivate();

Comment: UnitTests should verify *public observable behavior* which is *return values* and *communication with dependencies* The call of a private method is an *implementation detail* which should not be tested (directly).

Comment: I agree with Tim here: when you feel the need to test a private method, then you should rather spend your energy to rework your design so that you don't need to do that.

Comment: Hi,you two,I got your meaning. But in fact, sometimes we consider the memory useage and the safety. we must use the keywords private to modifier the method. If in another method there is a for/while cycle to call the private method. How can I verify the invoked times of the private method in unit test without the way above. However, I ask this question in order to know how to properly use verifyPrivate to verify call times of a private method, if you know, would you like to answer me? thx!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right, except one thing. You're spying on enum constant. And each enums constant is separate inner class. So you have to add two things:

1. Enum constant to `@PrepareForTest` with using `fullyQualifiedNames`, like `@PrepareForTest(values = { ConversionCommon.class, LengthConversion.class },  fullyQualifiedNames = "com.somepackage.ConversionCommon$INSTANCE")
2. Create a spy for instance: `PowerMockito.spy(ConversionCommon.INSTANCE)`
3. Replace constant with spy: `Whitebox.setInternalState(ConversionCommon.class, spy)`
4. Now, you can stub the spy method as usual `doNothing().when(spy, "setUnitCount");`

Code snippet for some abstract singleton implement via enum:

enum

```
public enum Singleton {

    INSTANCE;

    public void doSomething(){
        callPrivateMethod();
    }

    private void callPrivateMethod() {

    }
}
```

test

```
RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(value = Singleton.class, fullyQualifiedNames = "com.stackoverflow.q46212600.Singleton$INSTANCE")
public class ClassUseSingletonTest {

    @Test
    public void should_verify_enum_method() throws Exception {
        final Singleton spy = PowerMockito.spy(Singleton.INSTANCE);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(Singleton.class, spy);

        doNothing().when(spy, "callPrivateMethod");

        new ClassUseSingletone().doSomething("do");

        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(Singleton.INSTANCE, times(1)).invoke("callPrivateMethod");

    }

}
```

Full example, you may find [here](https://github.com/thekingnothing/stackoverflow/tree/master/q46212600)

Comment: It's very appreciate of you,and now I'm going try your  suggestion.Any way, thx for your answer!